# Ubuntu の apt-get install で CaboCha をインストールできない

Tags: ubuntu, cabocha

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS です。
The Ubuntu NLP Repository を利用して CaboCha をインストールしようとしたのですが、以下のメッセージが出て完了できません。
このエラーの対処方法などがあれば教えていただきたく思います。

```
UserName:~$ sudo apt-get install cabocha cabocha-dic-utf8パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています                
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
インストールすることができないパッケージがありました。おそらく、あり得ない状況を要求したか、(不安定版ディストリビューションを使用しているのであれば) 必要なパッケージがまだ作成されていなかったり Incoming から移動されていないことが考えられます。
以下の情報がこの問題を解決するために役立つかもしれません:

以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
cabocha : 依存: libcabocha2 (>= 0.64-1nlp2~0oneiric1) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
cabocha-dic-utf8 : 依存: cabocha-dic (>= 0.64-1nlp2~0oneiric1) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
E: 問題を解決することができません。壊れた変更禁止パッケージがあります。
```

Answer (score 1):

パッケージインストール中に電源を切ったりしたことはありませんか？あるなら

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

このコマンドを実行してみてください。駄目なら

```
sudo apt-get remove libuim0 libuim0-nox uim-common
```

を実行してみましょう。
[参考](https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=15916)

Answer (score 0):

前の回答はとりあえず残しときます。フォーラムで解決した方法を記述した方がいいですね。

---

Ubuntuの[公式フォーラム](https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=15916)から:
`/etc/apt/sources.list`に

> deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
>   deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

を追記してみてください。駄目なら公式フォーラムに書いてある他の方法も実行してみてください。